# iOS: Podfile lock errors

Tags: ios

I am programming for sharing an image to a server based on http socket communication. I came across the imageTransfer source from this link [source link](https://github.com/6david9/ImageTransfer)
When I run this project, it gives the following error in Xcode.

Diff: /Users/innovationlab/Downloads/ImageTransfer-master/Pods/../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

Diff: /Users/innovationlab/Downloads/ImageTransfer-master/Pods/Manifest.lock: No such file or directory

The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Could someone please help resolving this build errors please? I read that i need to do pod install
So, followed the below points,

```
1. sudo gem install cocoapods 
2. pod setup 
3. cd downloads/ImageTransfer-master  But, when i do install,
4. pod install
```

-> It gives error as "Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to find a specification for CBExtension."

Could someone please help me? –

Anyone please help?

Comment: Did you try to run `pod install` or reinstall CocoaPods? You can also try to delete the `Podfile.lock` and run `pod install` again.

Comment: Where it will be, .lock file, since i didn't find one any in this project folder? And, from which path i have to run pod install command ?

Comment: It should both be in your root project path.

Comment: I didn't find podfile.lock file in the project root directory, but i could see a file 'Podfile' unix executable file and a folder called 'Pods' in the same path.

Comment: This is not an executable https://github.com/6david9/ImageTransfer/blob/master/Podfile . Please read the cocoapods docks before using it.

Comment: Yeah, I am reading it. My question was, I didn't find that .lock file, so what should i do? Well, I run 'pod install' command now from the project root directory in terminal. This is the one it printed, [!] Pod::Executable pull
From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs 0ac6676..749ac33  master-> origin/master There is no tracking information for the current branch.Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details  git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: I don't know how to solve these errors?

Comment: I have done running these commands 1. sudo gem install cocoapods
2. pod setup
cd downloads/cd ImageTransfer-master
pod install    -> It gives error as "Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `CBExtension`."  Could someone please help me?